# Android RadioGroup isChecked

Tags: java, android

как можно проверить выбран ли какой-нибудь radioButton в radioGroup при нажатии кнопки.

Сейчас проверяю так: `if(radioBtnMale.isChecked() || radioBtnFemale.isChecked()){`, но думаю, что есть какой-нибудь метод в RadioGroup, который проверяет нажат ли хоть один из radioButton

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`radioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId()`

Вернет id выбранной радиокнопки в группе, если таковой нет вернет -1.

Так что можешь попробоывть

```
if (radioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId() == -1) {
    //ничего не выбрано
} else {
    //есть выбранная кнопка
}
```

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RadioGroup#getCheckedRadioButtonId()

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RadioGroup